# How many n digit numbers are there such that no three consecutive digits are 8?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My approach is to solve this problem using recursion. Let **T(n)** be the number of such n digit integers such that no 3 consecutive digits are 8.

Now there are a few cases:

Case 1: Last digit is not 8. So we are left with dealing with the remaining n-1 digits where the last digit can take any value except 8 i.e. the number of such numbers are **9T(n-1)** since last digit can be anything but 8 and we have to apply recursion on the remaining n-1 digits.

Case 2: Last digit is 8. Now, here it gets a bit tricky. If the last digit is 8, then again for the 2nd last digit, we have two options, it is either 8 or it is not 8. If it is not 8, we have no problem , the number of cases will be **9T(n-2)** since the last digit is 8, and the 2nd last is anything but 8, and we recurse on the previous n-2 digits in the integer.If the 2nd last digit is 8, then again, we must choose the 3rd last digit as not 8, so to avoid the subsequence **888**. This can be done in **9T(n-3)** ways as only the 3rd last digit should not be 8, and the remaining digits are already 8, so **9T(n-3)**, similarly recursing on the remaining n-3 digits.

So according to me number of such n digit integers such that no three digits are 8 can be solved by solving the recursion

**T(n) = 9T(n-3)+9T(n-2)+9T(n-1)**

The base cases are **T(1) = 9, T(2)=90, T(3) = 899**.

Is this solution correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks right to me :)

Comment: Okay.. great to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely right.

Just to check, it is fairly easy to count by cases that there are $18$ $4$-digit numbers that *does* contain $888$. Thus $T(4)=9000-18=8982$, which matches your recursive formula. Similarly, $T(5)$ should be $90000-261=89739$, which your formula also gives. We could check more with a program of course.

I also found the closed form formula for your recursion:
$$
T(n) = 0.9015\cdot9.991^n - 0.0126 \cdot 0.949^n \cdot \cos(2.12\cdot n) - 0.0155\cdot 0.949^n\cdot \sin(2.12\cdot n) \\
= [0.9015\cdot9.991^n]
$$
where $[\cdot]$ means rounded to nearest integer. (Exact algebraic values would involve roots of a cubic polynomial).